# meteor if document exists return true/false

Tags: meteor

How can I determine if a document exists within a collection in Meteor?

Edited:  New code.

the mongodb has a document with the ProductName: Apples
the inputproduct is "Apples"

```
var exists = Products.find({ProductName: inputproduct});
                    if(exists)
                    {
                        alert("it exists");
                    }else{
                        alert('doesnt exist');
                    }
```

all I get back is : "it exists" regardless of the value of inputproduct.  I have output what inputproduct is and it comes back "Apples" no problem.  Not sure what is going on here.  Tried it several ways using find or findOne and nothing.

Comment: That's how you would do it. Are you subscribing to the data as well?

Comment: Thanks for editing your code in! Please make sure to properly format it (it's kinda going on a trip to the right).

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it. However, meteor's collection.findOne will return the first object which matched, or undefined (which is falsy) if no match was found. Try this:

```
var exists = Products.findOne(selector, projection);
if(exists)
 {
    do something...
 }
```

Comment: you should still be using findOne. If you are going to change it to find, then you should be checking: if (exists.length > 0) {alerts('it exists');}else{...}

Comment: @GPicazo thanks, the 2nd example worked.  Super frusterating.  I swear I tried it earlier and it didn't work, but now it does.  Strange.

Comment: @GPicazo Thanks for the edit. I deleted my comments because they were no longer relevant.

Comment: @Lusty - If this fixes your issue, please mark the thread as answered.

Comment: But Collection.findOne() returns `undefined` if you call it before data has reached the client, even if a document actually exists. How can we differentiate between `undefined` due to the data not yet loaded and `undefined` because the document actually doesn't exist?